# GAE resource file FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, google-app-engine

In my appconfig.xml I have:

```
<resource-files>
    <include path="/emailtemplates/**.html" />
</resource-files>
```

When I try to read a file I always get a `FileNotFoundException`. I've tried it with and without a trailing `/` but it doesn't make any difference. I've also checked that the files exist in the packaged app.

My project consists of modules and I'm trying this on my local dev system on windows. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's difficult to say what's wrong when you give so little information. However I can give you an example of how i use resources.

- I use maven so my resource files go to `src\main\resources\*`
- In code I use `this.getClass().getResource("/" + filename).getPath()` to get the full path (note that in this case the '/' refers to the root of where the resources are. Usually '/' would refer to the root directory in the file system or in the working directory in Java)
- Then open the file like you'd normally do, ie. `new FileInputStream(pathFromAbove)`

My pom.xml is configured to include my resources:

```
<build>
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I moved my resource folder into the WEB-INF folder. The advantage is simply that I don't need any extra configuration in my appengine-web.xml which eliminates one point of failure.

Second, I now use the ServletContext to get the full path to my resource file. Before I just used `path` as argument for `new File` and that didn't work. That didn't come out anywhere in the docs I think. So my working piece of code to read a text file looks like:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(context.getRealPath(path)), "UTF-8");
while (scanner.hasNextLine())
    sb.append(scanner.nextLine());
scanner.close();
```

Comment: That works as well, you should've mentioned that you're trying to do this in a servlet. My solution will work with or without servlet. And yes, that's not in the App Engine docs, because that is Java (EE) specific behavior.